# Android Scrolling Activity Toolbar Subtitle not showing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am setting Toolbar subtitle like :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getExtra();
getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("subtitle");
```

It is working for other Activity but not working for Scrolling Activity

Comment: You need to post more code.

Comment: I hace the same probleme here